# PHP output encoding issues with UTF-8 strings from MySQL databases

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I know this question comes up in one form or another all the time on here, but I'm kind of at a loss on how to resolve it. I've got a PHP website that's running off of MySQL, that's showing some extended characters as a garbled mess. As far as I know it's all encoded as UTF-8, on every step from the content import to displaying it on the screen. Still, it's showing weird encoding issues. Here's the first test example (Natural Phënåm¥na, this is on purpose), which `mb_detect_encoding` identifies as UTF-8, which I can only get to display correctly with `utf8_decode`:

```
no utf8_decode: Natural PhÃ«nÃ¥mÂ¥na
utf8_decode: Natural Phënåm¥na
```

Second example, which never even utf8_decodes properly (should be an ümlaut and “typographer's quotes” (extended characters added on purpose, as a test:

```
no utf8_decode: This pÃ¼rson from â€œVancouver, Canadaâ€
utf8_decode: This pürson from �??Vancouver, Canada�?�
```

My initial thought was it was doubly encoded, but I don't think that's what's going on. Everything is displaying correctly in MySQL when I do queries on the command line.

Here's a rundown of all the things I've investigated:

- Content imported is verified to be UTF-8, imported with UTF-8 connection to MySQL
- MySQL Database, tables, columns are UTF-8, utf_unicode_*
- character_set_client, etc variables in MySQL set to utf8 on Amazon RDS
- PHP PDO connection is UTF-8, NAME set to UTF-8
- Both PHP header charset and HTML meta charset are UTF-8
- mb_detect_encoding is returning UTF-8 for both strings

So after a few hours of troubleshooting, I'm kind of at a loss. On a whim I even tried setting the HTML header/meta and PHP headers to ISO-8559-1, but that's not doing the trick either.

I last spent a while battling with Amazon RDS to get the right variables set, but otherwise I'm out of ideas.

```
mysql> show variables like '%character%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                     |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                      |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                      |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                      |
| character_set_filesystem | utf8                                      |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                      |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                      |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                      |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/mysql-5.5.40.R1/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

So I'm wondering, are there steps I'm missing? Something obvious? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Here's my PHP output script, for further clarification on the "output" that I mentioned:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
<html>
<header>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My test</title>
</header>
    <body>
<?php


    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", 
        "user", "password", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("my select statement");
$sth->execute();
$rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo mb_detect_encoding($row['name']);
    echo "<br>no utf8 decode: ". $row['name'] . "<br>\n";
    echo "single utf8 decode: ". utf8_decode($row['name']) . "<br>\n";
    echo "no utf8 decode: ". $row['description'] . "<br>\n";
    echo "single utf8 decode: ". (utf8_decode($row['description'])) . "<br>\n";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE #2**
I tried also just outputting these same characters into the browser directly from a PHP echo, and straight static HTML, and the characters display perfectly fine.

```
echo "“test ü ö”<br>"; ?>
<p>“test ü ö”</p>
```

Comment: is the output you are getting on the console or on the browser?

Comment: Add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8');` and take out the `utf8_decode()`.

Comment: I do actually already have this header outputting in my PHP script, first thing. Thanks!

Comment: To further confound things, I put `echo "“test ü ö”<br>";
?>“test ü ö”`, static outputs from HTML and PHP and got the right encoded characters.

Comment: error_log also outputs the raw value as `Natural PhÃ«nÃ¥mÂ¥na`, so it's definitely not related to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change all the `character_set%` fields, just the three that are affected by `SET NAMES utf8;`.

Don't use utf8_encode or decode.

You have probably messed up when storing.

This seems to recover the characters, but this not a viable fix:

```
CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT('pÃ¼rson from â€œVancouver, Canadaâ€' USING latin1)
             AS BINARY)
        USING utf8)
--> 'pürson from “Vancouver, Canada - spec',
```

In order to figure out what was done, please provide

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

for some cell that is not rendering properly.

Comment: I agree, it's better to figure out why it's storing wrong to begin with. It looks like it was happening en route from the python client, likely when it was being encoded for the REST API call.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that it is all in utf-8 in all the data flow, except when it is rendered on screen. I'm assuming on a browser, not a console. If it is so, check if the html has the `<meta charset="utf-8">` inside the `<head>` tag. Like in the html5 boilerplate https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/index.html

Comment: Yes, this is a fair point; I do in fact have that UTF-8 metatag on my markup output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like somehow on the MySQL level it was double-encoding UTF-8 characters in some of these fields. I was finally able to ascertain it via this great blog post [Getting out of MySQL Character Set Hell](https://www.blueboxcloud.com/insight/blog-article/getting-out-of-mysql-character-set-hell). Not 100% clear if it's being "double-encoded" when it's sent from Python, or when it hits the PHP API, but it's 90% of the answer, right there.